# VueJS: como criar uma condição para um v-model?

Tags: vue.js

O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho um **switch** feito com label e input checkbox e ele tem um valor default que vem do *data* da minha instância do Vue.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        slcModalidad: 0,
        chkPosNet: true,
    },

<label for="chkAllowPosNet" class="label-chk-allow">
     <input type="checkbox" id="chkAllowPosNet" name="chkAllowPosNet" v-model="chkPosNet">
          <div class="allow-text"></div>
          <div class="allow-toggle"></div>
</label>
```

Porém eu preciso que o valor default da variavel **chkPosNet** passe por uma condição para determinar se ele é true ou false, que no meu exemplo, seria se o **slcModalidad** fosse maior que 2. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Pensei em deixar o **chkPosNet** como **null** e criar um método para fazer a checagem, mas fiquei confuso se faço nos methods, no computed, mounted.... ou se eu posso fazer um v-if para o v-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte maneira, criei um **watcher** para ficar observando a variável **slcModalidad** e fiz uma vertificação dentro dele:

```
watch: {
            slcModalidad: function(){
                if(this.slcModalidad > 1){
                    this.chkPosNet = false
                }
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu watcher funciona, mas acho mais adequado transformar `chkPosNet` em uma propriedade computada:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        slcModalidad: 0
    },
    computed: {
        chkPosNet: function() {
            return this.slcModalidad <= 1;
        }
    },
    ....
```

Comment: sabe me dizer qual a vantagem de usar o computed no lugar do watcher?

Comment: É possível (não tenho certeza) que o watcher pese mais. As propriedades computadas são o recurso que o Vue oferece para fazer exatamente o que você quer, enquanto o watcher é uma coisa mais genérica.